# Infinite scroll built using knockout js not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I got a code snippet for infinite scrolling from this : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/adrienne/Y2WUN/).
I just changed the ajax url to `echojson.php` from `/echo/json/`.

This code works fine on chrome and firefox. But, its not working on IE 9.

File **echojson.php** contains:

```
<?php
     $json=array();
     for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
        $json[]='<div></div>';
     }
     echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

I am unable to understand why is it happening in case of IE9. Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem!

IE could not find JSON.stringify(). So, I just added the script as

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20121008/json2.js"></script>`.

Now it works flawlessly...